# Dashboard address gives 404

Tags: traefik

I am using Traefik in an ASF project, and the dashboard returns a 404 - http://localhost:8080. The routing rules still work perfectly I just have no visualization.

Can anyone suggest a reason / how to troubleshoot this?

Could No Extension found for Traefik/Traefik be the culprit?

**Traefik.toml**

```
################################################################
# Global configuration
################################################################

debug = true
logLevel = "INFO"

defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]

[entryPoints]
[entryPoints.http]
address = ":80"
[entryPoints.traefik]
address = ":8080"


################################################################
# API definition
################################################################

[api]
  entryPoint = "traefik"
  dashboard = true
  debug = true

################################################################
# Service Fabric provider
################################################################

[servicefabric]
clustermanagementurl = "http://localhost:19080"
apiversion = "3.0"
```

Log Entries:

```
time="2018-03-26T16:52:19+11:00" level=debug msg="Extension label found for acme.Hierarchy/acme.Hierarchy.Service with key traefik.frontend.rule and value PathPrefixStrip: /hierarchy" 
time="2018-03-26T16:52:19+11:00" level=debug msg="Extension label found for acme.Hierarchy/acme.Hierarchy.Service with key traefik.expose and value true"
time="2018-03-26T16:52:19+11:00" level=debug msg="Extension label found for acme.Hierarchy/acme.Hierarchy.Service with key traefik.frontend.passHostHeader and value true" 
time="2018-03-26T16:52:19+11:00" level=debug msg="**No Extension found for Traefik/Traefik"**  
time="2018-03-26T16:52:19+11:00" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider servicefabric: {"backends":{"fabric:/acme.Hierarchy/acme.Hierarchy.Service":{"servers":{"131665139249762233":{"url":"http://localhost:3001","weight":1}},"loadBalancer":{"method":"drr"}},"fabric:/Traefik/Traefik":{"servers":{"131665162941723979":{"url":"http://localhost:8080/","weight":1}},"loadBalancer":{"method":"drr"}}},"frontends":{"fabric:/acme.Hierarchy/ acme.Hierarchy.Service":{"entryPoints":["http"],"backend":"fabric:/acme.Hierarchy/acme.Hierarchy.Service","routes":{"frontend.rule":{"rule":"PathPrefixStrip: /hierarchy"}},"passHostHeader":true,"priority":0,"basicAuth":null,"headers":{}}}}"
time="2018-03-26T16:52:19+11:00" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider servicefabric" 
time="2018-03-26T16:52:29+11:00" level=info msg="Checking service fabric config" 
time="2018-03-26T16:52:29+11:00" level=debug msg="Extension label found for acme.Hierarchy/acme.Hierarchy.Service with key traefik.frontend.rule and value PathPrefixStrip: /hierarchy" 
time="2018-03-26T16:52:29+11:00" level=debug msg="Extension label found for acme.Hierarchy/acme.Hierarchy.Service with key traefik.expose and value true" 
time="2018-03-26T16:52:29+11:00" level=debug msg="Extension label found for acme.Hierarchy/acme.Hierarchy.Service with key traefik.frontend.passHostHeader and value true" 
time="2018-03-26T16:52:29+11:00" level=debug msg="No Extension found for Traefik/Traefik"
time="2018-03-26T16:52:29+11:00" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider servicefabric: {"backends":{"fabric:/acme.Hierarchy/acme.Hierarchy.Service":{"servers":{"131665139249762233":{"url":"http://localhost:3001","weight":1}},"loadBalancer":{"method":"drr"}},"fabric:/Traefik/Traefik":{"servers":{"131665162941723979":{"url":"http://localhost:8080/","weight":1}},"loadBalancer":{"method":"drr"}}},"frontends":{"fabric:/acme.Hierarchy/ acme.Hierarchy.Service":{"entryPoints":["http"],"backend":"fabric:/acme.Hierarchy/acme.Hierarchy.Service","routes":{"frontend.rule":{"rule":"PathPrefixStrip: /hierarchy"}},"passHostHeader":true,"priority":0,"basicAuth":null,"headers":{}}}}"
time="2018-03-26T16:52:29+11:00" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider servicefabric"
```